# How do I search wildcard files in mount points with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, mount-point

I’m trying to get all `*.log` files within mount point sub directories.

```
Command: [IO.Directory]::GetDirectories('e:\')
```

is showing me all directories; how do I search theses subdirectories for `*.log` files?

Answer (score 0):

```
get-childItem e:\ -recurse -Filter *.log
```

for your example I think you can do :

```
$alldirs=ls E: -recurse -directory

$alldirs|%{ 
    $nb=(ls -filter *.log).count
    if ($nb -gt $WARNING){
        "This Folder $_ is having > $nb < *.log files   "
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ... this helps but I got this script on msdn. I worked on a physical drive, but not on mount points. May you can have a look at this?  

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/de-DE/d0a3ce2c-a02d-4491-a872-2aa15d41b848/anzeige-von-dateien-pro-ordner?forum=powershell_de

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? get-childitem is working fine within mountpoints ...

Comment: this is the script. It's working great on physical drives, but if e: is having mount points the search won't work:

$DATASTORE = "E:\"

$WARNING=1
$ALLFOLDERS = [System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories($DATASTORE,"*","AllDirectories")

foreach ($Folder in $ALLFOLDERS) { 

 $ANZAHL= ([System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($Folder,"*.log","TopDirectoryOnly")).count
 
 if ($ANZAHL -gt $WARNING) {
 "This Folder $Folder is having > $ANZAHL < *.log files" 
 }
}

Comment: sorry, but I dont know how to add the source code. :-(